# Fail to call execve on linux after weeks

Tags: c++, linux, embedded-linux

I have encountered a very strange error. I execute a command with fixed args from a c++ code (execve). All was working fine during weeks.

And finally I get an error on one of my testing systems. After some monitoring and test, I understand the problem is the binary is not executed.

I have no logs and no error except the binary is not call (To be sure the problem is not on the binary, I have replace the target binary by a log script and he's not executed.)

A reboot has solved the problem, but I cannot figure why a fixed args command execution could fail, after dozen of time.

Does linux has some limitation I have hit ? There is the code who has fail :

```
int spawnWithRet(const std::string& file, const std::vector<std::string>& args)
{
    auto procArgs = prepareProcessArguments(file, args);
    pid_t pID = fork();
    if (pID == 0)
    {
        execCmd(file, procArgs);
        exit(0);
    }
    else
    {
        int status = -1;
        // We are the parent process
        if (waitpid(pID, &status, 0) < 0)
        {
            return status;
        }

        return status;
    }
}


void execCmd(const std::string& file, const std::vector<char*>& args)
{
    execv(file.c_str(), args.data());
    // If we reach this statement the process launch failed.
    // We have no way to inform the parent because we are detached from it.
    // Just log and continue to exit.
    sdn::log::Logger m_lg;
    sdn::log::configureLogger(m_lg, "LinuxT", "spawn");
    BOOST_LOG_SEV(m_lg, sdn::log::Sev::trace) << "Failed to execute [" << file << "]: [" << strerror(errno) << "].";
}


std::vector<char*> prepareProcessArguments(const std::string& file, const std::vector<std::string>& args)
{
    // Prepare process arguments.
    auto procArgs = std::vector<char*>{};
    procArgs.reserve(args.size() + 2); // +2 to include process name + terminator arg.
    // First add the process.
    procArgs.push_back(const_cast<char*>(file.c_str()));
    // Then the args.
    std::transform(args.begin(), args.end(), std::back_inserter(procArgs), [](const std::string& s) { return const_cast<char*>(s.c_str()); });
    // Last argument: a NULL pointer.
    procArgs.push_back(NULL);
    return procArgs;
}
```

**linux version :** 3.14.49-ge9cd4cc819 #2 Fri Oct 26 09:41:36 CEST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux

**command:** /usr/sbin/pppd /dev/ttyACM3 4000000 debug lcp-echo-failure 5 lcp-echo-interval 30 nodefaultroute noipdefault usepeerdns noauth unit 3 connect"

Comment: What specific error are you getting, and what command were you executing at the time?

Comment: I have edit the post, with this information

Comment: You still haven't told us the error. What does your log say? And you should *really* use `errno` *directly* after the failed call to `execv`. Or at least save it into a temporary variable that you use in the `strerror` call. The value of `errno` could have changed before the `strerror` call.

Comment: The problem is here, I have no error. No logs, The only reason I find any error, is that the PPPD binary is not running. (thanks for the errno value, I will fix this)

Comment: And there are no `pppd` logs that could help you understand any possible issue? No system logs?

Comment: Have you considered the possibilty that `fork` failed? Then `waitpid(-1, &status, 0)` would be called, which immediately returns -1.

Comment: I know the problem is on the code I have provide. So yes, the fork can be responsible, but why a fork can failed ? And this at every call ?

Comment: just a guess, .... "out of memory"? Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, I will monitor tightly my system and hope for other occurences.